# How to setup a folder for other people drop photos into?

Tags: photo-sharing, dropevent

I want to give people a link and have them click on the link and then be presented with a page where they can drag and drop photos into.

I've tried doing it on OneDrive but that requires everyone to have an MS account.

I've also tried Dropbox, but they want to send email invites to people.  This doesn't work for me because I'd have to go collect emails which they may or may not read ever read.

As far as Google Photos go, I am unclear on how to even set up a shared folder for others to access.

So is it possible for what I want?  I am open to any cloud provider or social network or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a **https://dropevent.com/** which may serve your purpose:

[image: 0]

Another option would be to create a OneDrive account with a shared folder that allows editing. Users, however, will not be allowed to anonymously upload files so you would need to set up a second OneDrive account and give your buddies the login details of the second account and they could use those credentials to upload files via a browser. Of course, this isn't a troll-proof solution.

The proper way would be to set up an FTP server/folder for example with FileZilla (portable version is available too).

Comment: Second option is what I ended up dong.  It's not ideal, but it's the only free solution that's reasonably hassle free.